# INSERT/UPDATE in same query from previous SELECT with some singularities

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, update, insert

I'm trying to perform a `INSERT|UPDATE` by selecting data from another DB and this is what I have so far:

```
INSERT INTO pdone.reps 
    (veeva_rep_id,display_name,username,`first`,`last`,email) 
SELECT Id, CONCAT(UCASE(LEFT(firstname, 1)),UCASE(LEFT(lastname, 1)),username, firstname, lastname, email 
FROM veeva.`user` 
WHERE Id = "00580000003UB5VAAW"
```

- First problem, I got this error:

> [Err] 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual
>   that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax
>   to use near 'from veeva.`user` WHERE Id = "00580000003UB5VAAW"' at
>   line 1

and I'm not sure what is wrong on the query, any advice?

- `firstname` could be JOHN or John or jOhn or any and I want to normalize as John, is `UCASE(LEFT(firstname, 1)` fine for this? The same apply to `lastname`
- If `firstname` is JOHN and `lastname` is DOE then `username` should be `John Doe` with a space between them, is my `CONCATENATE` right?
- I should insert some statics fields like one URL or just `VEEVA` how I can do that? Values are not present on the query shown here but is just add two more columns to the insert `avatar_url` and `rep_type`
- I am planning to add [`ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) but can be possible to add a restriction based on a column? Lets said UPDATE only if now > `lastSyncDate`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've made a function where you just put the string and the output will be in `Capital Letters`:

```
    DELIMITER //

    CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` FUNCTION `LCAPITAL`(eCADENA VARCHAR(150)) RETURNS varchar(150) CHARSET latin1
        DETERMINISTIC
    BEGIN

    DECLARE vPOSICION INT DEFAULT 0; 
    DECLARE vTMP VARCHAR(150) DEFAULT ''; 
    DECLARE vRESULTADO VARCHAR(150) DEFAULT '';
    DECLARE vCADENA VARCHAR(150) DEFAULT '';
    IF eCADENA IS NULL THEN
        SET vRESULTADO='';
        RETURN vRESULTADO;
    ELSE
        SET vCADENA=LCASE(eCADENA);
        REPEAT 
            SET vPOSICION=LOCATE(' ', vCADENA); 
            IF vPOSICION=0 THEN 
                SET vPOSICION=CHAR_LENGTH(vCADENA); 
            END IF; 
            SET vTMP=LEFT(vCADENA,vPOSICION); 
            IF CHAR_LENGTH(vTMP) < 4 THEN 
                SET vRESULTADO=CONCAT(vRESULTADO, vTMP); 
            ELSE 
                SET vRESULTADO=CONCAT(vRESULTADO, UPPER(LEFT(vTMP,1)),SUBSTRING(vTMP,2)); 
            END IF; 
            SET vCADENA=RIGHT(vCADENA,CHAR_LENGTH(vCADENA)-vPOSICION); 
        UNTIL CHAR_LENGTH(vCADENA) = 0 
        END REPEAT; 
        RETURN CONCAT(UPPER(LEFT(vRESULTADO,1)),MID(vRESULTADO,2,150)); 
    END IF;
    END

    //
    DELIMITER ;
```

Example:

```
    INSERT INTO pdone.reps 
        (veeva_rep_id,display_name,username,`first`,`last`,email) 
    SELECT 
        Id, 
        CONCAT(LCAPITAL(firstname),' ',LCAPITAL(lastname)) AS display_name,
        username, 
        firstname, 
        lastname, 
        email 
    FROM veeva.`user` 
    WHERE Id = "00580000003UB5VAAW";
```

Comment: I'm getting this error `DECLARE vPOSICION INT DEFAULT 0;
[Err] 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 5` while try to execute the query for create the function, any advice?

Comment: Mysql sees the ';' delimiters in the function and breaks your `CREATE FUNCTION` statement.

To avoid this, change the delimiter before you define the function, and then change it back afterward:

Like:

DELIMITER //

-- your create function definition statement here

//
DELIMITER ;
As in your code the first ; semicolon was found at line 8, it tried to execute it the code up to the ';', and the syntax was invalid because it was incomplete (`BEGIN` without `END`).

Source: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22552472/mariadb-error-creating-function-when-it-worked-on-mysql

Comment: Still not working for me, can you just edit your answer by adding the `DELIMITERS` part?

Comment: I've done. Anyway, I'm not running MariaDB at this time to be sure.

Comment: It works fine, so tested on MariaDB. thx

Answer (score 4):

Insert query:

```
INSERT INTO pdone.reps (veeva_rep_id,display_name,username,first,last,email,avatar_url,rep_type) 
SELECT 
    Id, 
    CONCAT(UCASE(MID(firstname,1,1)),LCASE(MID(firstname,2)),' ',UCASE(MID(lastname,1,1)),LCASE(MID(lastname,2))),
    username, 
    firstname, 
    lastname, 
    email,
    'www.some_static_url.com',
    '1' 
FROM veeva.user 
WHERE Id = "00580000003UB5VAAW"
```

It will print Only first letter capital from both First & Last name.

Answer (score 1):

```
CONCAT(UCASE(LEFT(firstname, 1)),UCASE(LEFT(lastname, 1))
```

You missed one more closed parenthesis in your statement

```
CONCAT(UCASE(LEFT(firstname, 1)),UCASE(LEFT(lastname, 1)))
```

2.The query you wrote for concatenation returns only first letter in capital letters of both fist and last names and it  doesn't print space between them.

example :First name:JOHN,Last name :DOE

- Result:JD

  so use following for concatenation

INSERT INTO pdone.reps         (veeva_rep_id,display_name,username,first,last,email)
SELECT
Id,
CONCAT(UCASE(LEFT(firstname, 1)),SUBSTRING(firstname,2),'     ',UCASE(LEFT(firstname, 1)),SUBSTRING(firstname,2)),
username,
firstname,
lastname,
email
FROM veeva.user
WHERE Id = '00580000003UB5VAAW';

Comment: This doesn't work I got this error: `[Err] 1582 - Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'UCASE'`

Comment: I for got add right parenthesis after second U CASE that's why it shows Incorrect parameter count error.now i updated query please use it.